# RSpec - Date should be between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How can I test a date to see if it's between two dates? I know I can do two greater-than and less-than comparisons but I want an RSpec method to check the "betweeness" of the date.

For example:

```
it "is between the time range" do
    expect(Date.now).to be_between(Date.yesterday, Date.tomorrow)
end
```

I tried `expect(range).to cover(subject)` but no luck.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Date.today.should be_between(Date.today - 1.day, Date.today + 1.day)`

Comment: This works perfect. I'm surprised I couldn't find any documentation for it. Don't even need to define it.

Comment: Prefer `be_within(1.day).of(Date.today)`.

Answer (score 12):

Both of the syntaxes you wrote are correct RSpec:

```
it 'is between the time range' do
  expect(Date.today).to be_between(Date.yesterday, Date.tomorrow)
end

it 'is between the time range' do
  expect(Date.yesterday..Date.tomorrow).to cover Date.today
end
```

If you are not using Rails you won't have `Date::yesterday` or `Date::tomorrow` defined. You'll need to manually adjust it:

```
it 'is between the time range' do
  expect(Date.today).to be_between(Date.today - 1, Date.today + 1)
end
```

The first version works due to RSpec's built in [predicate matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers). This matcher understand methods being defined on objects, and delegates to them as well as a possible `?` version. For `Date`, the predicate [`Date#between?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) comes from including `Comparable` (see link).

The second version works because RSpec defines the [cover](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/built-in-matchers/cover-matcher) matcher.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try it myself, but according to [this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-6/docs/built-in-matchers/cover-matcher) you should use it a bit differently:

```
it "is between the time range" do    
  (Date.yesterday..Date.tomorrow).should cover(Date.now)
end
```

Comment: I noted in the question that I've already tried that and I had no luck. I guess you missed it.

Comment: Oh right, I thought there's a difference between `expect` and `should`. Apologies. Check out @spullen's answer.

Comment: Not much difference. Although this solution might work, I don't really like how it does the comparison with dates/times.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a matcher, check https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Matchers

It could be

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_between do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual[:bottom] <= expected && actual[:top] >= expected
  end
end
```

It allows you

```
it "is between the time range" do
    expect(Date.now).to be_between(:bottom => Date.yesterday, :top => Date.tomorrow)
end
```

Comment: Great solution but it seems like RSpec has be_between already defined (according to my application).